# Disable label generation in Django forms

Tags: django

How do I disable the generation of the `<label>` tag in django forms? I read around and it seemed like setting `auto_id=False` would do the trick but it did not.

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"id": "signup-username", "name": "username", "placeholder": "Username"}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"id": "signup-firstname", "name": "firstname", "placeholder": "First Name"}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"id": "signup-lastname", "name": "lastname", "placeholder": "Last Name"}))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={"id": "signup-email", "name": "email", "placeholder": "Email"}))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=32, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"id": "signup-password", "name": "password", "placeholder": "Password"}))
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(max_length=32, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"id": "signup-confirm-password", "name": "confirm-password", "placeholder": "Confirm Password"}))

>>> f = RegistrationForm(auto_id-False)
>>> f = RegistrationForm(auto_id=False)
>>> print(f)
<tr><th><label for="signup-username">Username:</label></th><td><input id="signup-username" maxlength="50" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="signup-firstname">First name:</label></th><td><input id="signup-firstname" maxlength="50" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="signup-lastname">Last name:</label></th><td><input id="signup-lastname" maxlength="50" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="signup-email">Email:</label></th><td><input id="signup-email" maxlength="50" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="signup-password">Password:</label></th><td><input id="signup-password" maxlength="32" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="signup-confirm-password">Confirm password:</label></th><td><input id="signup-confirm-password" maxlength="32" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" /></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = forms.CharField(label=False, widget=...)
```